# Recursive Permutation C++

Tags: c++, recursion, permutation

I have problem with assignment, we need to implement recursive permutation in c++ for numbers.
Here is the code which is partly working, but missing some numbers.
I can't find where the problem is.

This code does work, but not exactly the right way.

This code take and array of number with size of that array.
in this case I am trying to solve the problem which appears when I send array longer than 3 numbers. If I send 3 numbers, output is:

```
///
1 2 3 /
1 3 2 /
3 1 2 /
2 1 3 /
2 3 1 /
3 2 1 /
```

Output in this case is correct. But when I set array to 4 and send size of it 4 I get:

```
///
1 2 3 4 /
1 2 4 3 /
1 4 2 3 /
4 1 2 3 / 
**2 1 3   /
2 3 1   /
3 2 1   /**
3 2 1 4 /
3 2 4 1 / 
3 4 2 1 /
4 3 2 1 /
```

Output is partly correct, but some numbers are missing.

Program should give output of all possible variations of numbers in array

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool nextPermutation(int[],int);
void swap(int&, int&);
int Maxind(int[],int);
int Minind(int[],int);
void print (int[], int);
bool test (int[], int);
int fl=0;


int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4};
    nextPermutation(a,4);
    return 0;
}


void print(int a[], int s) {
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++) 
    { 
        cout<<a[i]<<" "; 
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
bool nextPermutation(int a[], int s)
{
    int i=Maxind(a,s);
    if(fl==0)
        print(a,s);
    if(i!=0) {
        swap(a[i],a[i-1]);
        nextPermutation(a,s); 
    }

    else if(i==0 && test(a,s))
    {
        int p=a[0];
        for(int i=0; i<=s-2; i++)
            a[i]=a[i+1];
        fl=1;
        nextPermutation(a,s-1);
        a[s-1]=p;
        fl=0;
        nextPermutation(a,s);            
    }
    else 
        return false;
}

bool test (int a[], int s) {    
    if (Maxind(a,s)==0 && Minind(a,s)==s-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    int t=a; a=b; b=t;
}

int Maxind(int a[], int s)
{
    int m=a[0], ind=0;
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++) 
        if(m<a[i]) {
            m=a[i];
            ind=i;
        }
    return ind;
}

int Minind(int a[], int s)
{
    int m=a[0], ind=0;
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++) 
        if(m>a[i]) {
            m=a[i];
            ind=i;
        }
    return ind;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger line by line, while watching all variables?

Comment: If you want some help it would useful if you briefly explain what your code does etc. Did you step through the application in a debugger?

Comment: Some things I notice: `fl` is some global variable used only in `nextPermutation` which is generally bad design and error-prone. Then: You're doing permutation, but somehow depend on the numeric order of the elements (with `Maxind` / `Minind`). Permutation has nothing to do with the numeric order of the elements to permutate and therefore your algorithm shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: that implementation looks complex for such problem. search for "k permutation of n element with or without repetition"

Comment: This code has been written by our lecturer, it is a bit complex, I was trying to fix it, but ended up with nothing...I do not have much exp with programming and this task is out of my knowledge ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to send all numbers of possibilities for permutation.

If you change your `main` function you will get the solution. Add a `loop` in main funciton and send to `nextPermutation(a, i)` with variable `i`

```
int main() {
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        int a[]= {1,2,3,4};
        nextPermutation(a,i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should debug your program and also i figure out that your s value is decrasing here:

```
else if(i==0 && test(a,s)) {
    int p=a[0];
    for(int i=0; i<=s-2; i++) {
        a[i]=a[i+1];
    }
    fl=1;
    nextPermutation(a,s-1);
    //*** careful you are decreasing s here and your output gives 3 numbers. !!***
    a[s]=p;
    fl=0;
    nextPermutation(a,s);
}
```

Comment: It should work . Change your code and try it. As i understand you want something like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives different output...((( \1   \1 2 \ 2 1 \ 1 2 3 .... and so on

Comment: How your output should be ? I could not understand correctly i guess. You need to give more information.

Comment: Output, if I send array 1,2,3 should be / 1 2 3 (first raw)/ 1 3 2 (second raw) / 3 1 2 (third raw) / 2 1 3 (so on..)/ 2 3 1 / 3 2 1 / until all the possible variations will be retrieved. This program works for 1,2,3 array , but doesn't work for larger than that (1,2,3,4 ...

Comment: if not decrease there, it will output only half on permutation and then crash it

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the nextPermutation method of your code as follows and it worked.

```
bool nextPermutation(int a[], int s)
{
    if(s == 0)
        return false;
    int i=Maxind(a,s);
    if(fl==0)
        print(a,s);
    if(i!=0) {
        swap(a[i],a[i-1]);
        if(fl == 0)
            nextPermutation(a,s); 
        else{    
            int temp = fl;
            fl = 0;
            nextPermutation(a,s+temp);
        }
    }
    else if(i==0){
        int p=a[0];
        for(int i=0; i<=s-2; i++)
            a[i]=a[i+1];
        a[s-1]=p;
        fl+=1;
        nextPermutation(a,s-1);
    }
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Also I removed the methods test and Minind as they are not useful in my code.